# License manager problem after changing rc.local?

Tags: linux, gnome, matlab

I am very new to Linux - so please don't be irritated by the potential weirdness of that question.

I am running GNOME 3 on a USB Stick where the host computer is running on Windows. Since I did not want to change the time for any other user I included the command `hwclock --systochc --localtime` in my `rc.local file` (before the `exit 0`).

When I want to start matlab from that stick I do not get a license from our work server and matlab gives me the following error message:

```
License Manager Error -15 rc.local
MATLAB is unable to connect to the license server. 

This script is exeCheck that the license manager has been started, and 
that the MATLAB client machine can communicate0" on success or any 
other value on error with the license server
```

The weird thing is that it still works when I use the USB Stick on my own laptop and connect via VPN to another network. This made me think that is potentially a problem of the license server and not of my stick?

The only thing I have recently changed was to add the `hwclock` command. Since the error message tells me something about `rc.local`, I wonder whether there can be some kind of interference?

I deleted the command and tried again off course but it still won't work.

Comment: Not familiar with the MATLAB license manager, but I think it that either networking doesn't work completely (e.g. no public internet) with the USB stick in the Windows box, while it does on your laptop with VPN. Or the MATLAB license manager looks at your system configuration, and your laptop and the Windows box are different enough it balks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Internet works on both set ups. It is the same USB Stick on my laptop and on the windows host PC. So basically the same system config, no?

Comment: No, it's a completely different hardware config - your windows PC doesn't have the same hardware as your laptop. Which may cause different drivers for networking to be loaded, even from the same USB stick, which in turn may cause different network interface names, etc. One can debug what's happening (`ip addr` to see network interfaces, `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to see what the license manager is trying to do over the network), but for someone new to Linux this is not particularly easy. And it's difficult to assist you in this on a Q&A site.

Comment: I guess you are right :( Thanks for your help and when I might come up with a solution one day I will post it here